# PHP if statement within if statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm building a php site where i want the user to create his company.

The script is checking if the user has any companies registered already and then it should display if he does or doesn't.

If he doesnt have a registered company, he should see a form where he can register.

If he choose to register a company the script will check for any company with the same name or insert the row.

My only problem is that when there's already a company with that name the echo doesnt display.

I have written inside the code where the problem is.

```
<?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("mysql","USER","PASS","DB");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

            $result_get_companies = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM companies WHERE userid='". $login_session ."' ORDER BY companyid ASC") or die(mysqli_error());

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result_get_companies) >= 1) {

                while($row_companies = mysqli_fetch_array( $result_get_companies )) {

                $result_get_company_owner = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid='". $login_session ."'")                 or die(mysqli_error());

                $company_owner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_get_company_owner);

                    echo 'THIS WORKS';
                }

            } else {

                if (isset($_POST['create_first_company']) && !empty($_POST['company_name'])) {

                    $company_name_unsafe = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['company_name']);
                    $company_name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/","",$company_name_unsafe );

                    $check_companies = "SELECT companyid FROM companies WHERE company_name='". $company_name ."'";
                    $what_to_do_companies = mysqli_query($con,$check_companies);

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($what_to_do_companies) != 0) {

                        echo 'THIS DOESNT WORK
                                It does register that is should go here
                                because it does not insert new row.
                                and when the value is = 0 it does go
                                to else ELSE below and insert row.';

                    } else {

                        $result_create_company = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO companies (companyname) 
                                                                    VALUES ('". $login_session ."')") 
                                                                    or die(mysqli_error());

                        echo 'THIS WORKS';  

                    }

                } else {

                    echo 'THIS WORKS!';

                }

            }

?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `INSERT INTO companies (companyname)` be `INSERT INTO companies (company_name)` ?

Comment: ...or *vice-versa* ^

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Guys THANK YOU. I have never been in school for php so i didnt know about that error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ! this made me see the error. Thank you so much !

Comment: I think it is more of logic issue than any other. If you note, if company is already registered, then it will not even go to ELSE part. It goes to ELSE part only when company is not registered. And as company is not registered, so when it goes to else part, it skips the IF because it doesnt find any company...hope that clears?